# postgreSQL working with PGAdmin3

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with the household_objects_database , I have installed it from
[link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sql_database/Tutorials/Installing%20a%20PostgreSQL%20Server) , but I have faced a problem in the step of working with PGAdmin3 , there was an error telling me that the version of pgadmin isn't suitable to work with the version of postgreSQl , so I tried to upgrade the version of PGADmin , but I got amessage telling me that :
pgadmin3 is already the newest version ,so I tried to upgrade the postgreSQL ,but it is the newest version too , what can I do to solve this problem ?

I'm using ROS furete on Ubuntu 11.10 .

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56804/postgresql-working-with-pgadmin3/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2013-03-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-06**:
@Ricky
Do u have any idea about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug from Ubuntu 11.10, stated [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pgadmin3/+bug/881015).

To solve this problem, check [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66099/how-can-i-update-pgadmin3-to-v1-14) or [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79137/installing-pgadmin-3-for-ubuntu-11-10-and-postgresql-9-1).

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-09**:
Thanks, I have fixed it using :
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/postgres
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pgadmin3